# ¿Cómo recorrer un array JSON en PHP?

Tags: json, array, api

Holas buenos este código tengo para consumir una web service pero no logro recorrer el array espero me ayuden se los agradezco.

PHP

```
$obj = json_decode($url, true); 
var_dump($obj);
```

IMPRESION

```
{"buscarTitularidadResponse":{"respuestaTitularidad":{"respuestaTitularidad":[{"registro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE","libro":"REGISTRO DE PREDIOS","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMASA","tipoDocumento":"L.E.","numeroDocumento":"08047473","numeroPartida":57025741,"estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA","oficina":"CALLAO","direccion":"MZ G1 LOTE 16    SECTOR 5 - ASENTAMIENTO HUMANO BOCANEGRA - DPTO: LIMA PROV: CALLAO DIST: CALLAO"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE","libro":"SECCION ESPECIAL DE PREDIOS RURALES","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":10186000,"numeroPartida":11010213,"estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA","oficina":"JUANJUI","direccion":"UBICACION RURAL VALLE ALTO HUALLAGA/CASERIO BAJO PORONGO/EL DIAMANTE I PARCELA 8_3359085_114015 AREA Ha. 4.8541 U.C. 114015/HH.CC. 8_3359085_3 UCHIZA - TOCACHE - SAN MARTIN"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":10186000,"numeroPartida":53279675,"numeroPlaca":"98331D ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA","oficina":"LIMA"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":"01090583","numeroPartida":60650936,"numeroPlaca":"90226S ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA","oficina":"TARAPOTO"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMASA CIRILA","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":31620166,"numeroPartida":60521874,"numeroPlaca":"H1Y284 ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL VII - SEDE HUARAZ","oficina":"HUARAZ"}]}}}
```

Comment: ¿Qué buscas obtener de la respuesta que tienes específicamente?

Comment: Los datos despues de {"buscarTitularidadResponse":{"respuestaTitularidad":{"respuestaTitularidad":[{"registro", etc

Comment: array(1) { ["buscarTitularidadResponse"]=> array(1) { ["respuestaTitularidad"]=> array(1) { ["respuestaTitularidad"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(12) { ["registro"]=> string(30) "REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE" ........  hay varios arrays

Comment: Y con qué código intentas obtener algo de la respuesta?

Comment: intentaba hacer esto $data = $obj ['buscarTitularidadResponse']['respuestaTitularidad']['respuestaTitularidad']['registro']; para obtenerlo pero en esto es distinto porque muestra varios arrays

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo tu json es el siguiente:

---

```
{"buscarTitularidadResponse":{"respuestaTitularidad":{"respuestaTitularidad":[{"registro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE","libro":"REGISTRO DE PREDIOS","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMASA","tipoDocumento":"L.E.","numeroDocumento":"08047473","numeroPartida":57025741,"estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA","oficina":"CALLAO","direccion":"MZ G1 LOTE 16    SECTOR 5 - ASENTAMIENTO HUMANO BOCANEGRA - DPTO: LIMA PROV: CALLAO DIST: CALLAO"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE","libro":"SECCION ESPECIAL DE PREDIOS RURALES","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":10186000,"numeroPartida":11010213,"estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA","oficina":"JUANJUI","direccion":"UBICACION RURAL VALLE ALTO HUALLAGA/CASERIO BAJO PORONGO/EL DIAMANTE I PARCELA 8_3359085_114015 AREA Ha. 4.8541 U.C. 114015/HH.CC. 8_3359085_3 UCHIZA - TOCACHE - SAN MARTIN"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":10186000,"numeroPartida":53279675,"numeroPlaca":"98331D ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA","oficina":"LIMA"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":"01090583","numeroPartida":60650936,"numeroPlaca":"90226S ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA","oficina":"TARAPOTO"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMASA CIRILA","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":31620166,"numeroPartida":60521874,"numeroPlaca":"H1Y284 ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL VII - SEDE HUARAZ","oficina":"HUARAZ"}]}}}
```

Y como bien, hiciste, para transforarlo a array usaste lo siguiente:

---

```
$obj = json_decode($url, true);
```

Esto da una respuesta así:

---

```
Array
(
    [buscarTitularidadResponse] => Array
        (
            [respuestaTitularidad] => Array
                (
                    [respuestaTitularidad] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [registro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE
                                    [libro] => REGISTRO DE PREDIOS
                                    [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [nombre] => TOMASA
                                    [tipoDocumento] => L.E.
                                    [numeroDocumento] => 08047473
                                    [numeroPartida] => 57025741
                                    [estado] => ACTIVA
                                    [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA
                                    [oficina] => CALLAO
                                    [direccion] => MZ G1 LOTE 16    SECTOR 5 - ASENTAMIENTO HUMANO BOCANEGRA - DPTO: LIMA PROV: CALLAO DIST: CALLAO
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [registro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE
                                    [libro] => SECCION ESPECIAL DE PREDIOS RURALES
                                    [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [nombre] => TOMAS
                                    [tipoDocumento] => DNI
                                    [numeroDocumento] => 10186000
                                    [numeroPartida] => 11010213
                                    [estado] => ACTIVA
                                    [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA
                                    [oficina] => JUANJUI
                                    [direccion] => UBICACION RURAL VALLE ALTO HUALLAGA/CASERIO BAJO PORONGO/EL DIAMANTE I PARCELA 8_3359085_114015 AREA Ha. 4.8541 U.C. 114015/HH.CC. 8_3359085_3 UCHIZA - TOCACHE - SAN MARTIN
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [registro] => REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES
                                    [libro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR
                                    [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [nombre] => TOMAS
                                    [tipoDocumento] => DNI
                                    [numeroDocumento] => 10186000
                                    [numeroPartida] => 53279675
                                    [numeroPlaca] => 98331D 
                                    [estado] => ACTIVA
                                    [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA
                                    [oficina] => LIMA
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [registro] => REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES
                                    [libro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR
                                    [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [nombre] => TOMAS
                                    [tipoDocumento] => DNI
                                    [numeroDocumento] => 01090583
                                    [numeroPartida] => 60650936
                                    [numeroPlaca] => 90226S 
                                    [estado] => ACTIVA
                                    [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA
                                    [oficina] => TARAPOTO
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [registro] => REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES
                                    [libro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR
                                    [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
                                    [nombre] => TOMASA CIRILA
                                    [tipoDocumento] => DNI
                                    [numeroDocumento] => 31620166
                                    [numeroPartida] => 60521874
                                    [numeroPlaca] => H1Y284 
                                    [estado] => ACTIVA
                                    [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL VII - SEDE HUARAZ
                                    [oficina] => HUARAZ
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Y de acuerdo a tu respuesta dijiste que quieres obtener los valores de `respuestaTitularidad` los cuales son (extrayendo poco el código):

---

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [registro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE
        [libro] => REGISTRO DE PREDIOS
        [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [nombre] => TOMASA
        [tipoDocumento] => L.E.
        [numeroDocumento] => 08047473
        [numeroPartida] => 57025741
        [estado] => ACTIVA
        [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA
        [oficina] => CALLAO
        [direccion] => MZ G1 LOTE 16    SECTOR 5 - ASENTAMIENTO HUMANO BOCANEGRA - DPTO: LIMA PROV: CALLAO DIST: CALLAO
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [registro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE
        [libro] => SECCION ESPECIAL DE PREDIOS RURALES
        [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [nombre] => TOMAS
        [tipoDocumento] => DNI
        [numeroDocumento] => 10186000
        [numeroPartida] => 11010213
        [estado] => ACTIVA
        [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA
        [oficina] => JUANJUI
        [direccion] => UBICACION RURAL VALLE ALTO HUALLAGA/CASERIO BAJO PORONGO/EL DIAMANTE I PARCELA 8_3359085_114015 AREA Ha. 4.8541 U.C. 114015/HH.CC. 8_3359085_3 UCHIZA - TOCACHE - SAN MARTIN
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [registro] => REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES
        [libro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR
        [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [nombre] => TOMAS
        [tipoDocumento] => DNI
        [numeroDocumento] => 10186000
        [numeroPartida] => 53279675
        [numeroPlaca] => 98331D 
        [estado] => ACTIVA
        [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA
        [oficina] => LIMA
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [registro] => REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES
        [libro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR
        [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [nombre] => TOMAS
        [tipoDocumento] => DNI
        [numeroDocumento] => 01090583
        [numeroPartida] => 60650936
        [numeroPlaca] => 90226S 
        [estado] => ACTIVA
        [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA
        [oficina] => TARAPOTO
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [registro] => REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES
        [libro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR
        [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [nombre] => TOMASA CIRILA
        [tipoDocumento] => DNI
        [numeroDocumento] => 31620166
        [numeroPartida] => 60521874
        [numeroPlaca] => H1Y284 
        [estado] => ACTIVA
        [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL VII - SEDE HUARAZ
        [oficina] => HUARAZ
    )
```

Para recorrerlos necesitaremos el siguiente código php:

---

```
<?php
$json = '{"buscarTitularidadResponse":{"respuestaTitularidad":{"respuestaTitularidad":[{"registro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE","libro":"REGISTRO DE PREDIOS","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMASA","tipoDocumento":"L.E.","numeroDocumento":"08047473","numeroPartida":57025741,"estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA","oficina":"CALLAO","direccion":"MZ G1 LOTE 16    SECTOR 5 - ASENTAMIENTO HUMANO BOCANEGRA - DPTO: LIMA PROV: CALLAO DIST: CALLAO"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE","libro":"SECCION ESPECIAL DE PREDIOS RURALES","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":10186000,"numeroPartida":11010213,"estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA","oficina":"JUANJUI","direccion":"UBICACION RURAL VALLE ALTO HUALLAGA/CASERIO BAJO PORONGO/EL DIAMANTE I PARCELA 8_3359085_114015 AREA Ha. 4.8541 U.C. 114015/HH.CC. 8_3359085_3 UCHIZA - TOCACHE - SAN MARTIN"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":10186000,"numeroPartida":53279675,"numeroPlaca":"98331D ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA","oficina":"LIMA"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMAS","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":"01090583","numeroPartida":60650936,"numeroPlaca":"90226S ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL III - SEDE MOYOBAMBA","oficina":"TARAPOTO"},{"registro":"REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES","libro":"REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR","apPaterno":"SANCHEZ","apMaterno":"SANCHEZ","nombre":"TOMASA CIRILA","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":31620166,"numeroPartida":60521874,"numeroPlaca":"H1Y284 ","estado":"ACTIVA","zona":"ZONA REGISTRAL VII - SEDE HUARAZ","oficina":"HUARAZ"}]}}}';

$mObjeto = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ( $mObjeto['buscarTitularidadResponse']['respuestaTitularidad']['respuestaTitularidad'] as $mPersona ) {
    echo $mPersona['registro'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

La variable `$mPersona` contendrá toda la información del array perteneciente al valor, es decir, por ejemplo esto:

---

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [registro] => REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE
        [libro] => REGISTRO DE PREDIOS
        [apPaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [apMaterno] => SANCHEZ
        [nombre] => TOMASA
        [tipoDocumento] => L.E.
        [numeroDocumento] => 08047473
        [numeroPartida] => 57025741
        [estado] => ACTIVA
        [zona] => ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA
        [oficina] => CALLAO
        [direccion] => MZ G1 LOTE 16    SECTOR 5 - ASENTAMIENTO HUMANO BOCANEGRA - DPTO: LIMA PROV: CALLAO DIST: CALLAO
    )
```

Puedes acceder a sus valores definiendo su clave como `$mPersona['registro']`, `$mPersona['apPaterno']`, `$mPersona['nombre']`, etc.

Comment: Ya solucione amigo gracias. Como los arrays no son los mismos de siempre tengo que recorrerlos. abajo lo publique.

Comment: ok, amigo, de todos modos considera siempre otras alternativas de lograrlo, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione. Disculpen
Por si alguien lo necesita

```
$listaItems = $sunart["buscarTitularidadResponse"]["respuestaTitularidad"]["respuestaTitularidad"];

 for ($i = 0; $i<count($listaItems); $i++){

     echo "TITULO GENERAL: ".$listaItems[$i]["registro"]."<br>";
     echo "SUB GENERAL: ".$listaItems[$i]["libro"]."<br>";
     echo "PATERNO: ".$listaItems[$i]["apPaterno"]."<br>";
     echo "MATERNO: ".$listaItems[$i]["apMaterno"]."<br>";
     echo "NOMBRES: ".$listaItems[$i]["nombre"]."<br>";

}
```